# Use Ncat in Heroku for Proxy Authentication

Tags: heroku, nmap

I need to use a proxy over ssh connection and I need the ncat tool.
But I cannot find any articles how can I setup nmap-ncat and use it.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it using https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
in Aptfile just add nmap